# ORACLE 11G Data base administration

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Dear friends, 
             I using oracle 11g database, I want to create a number of users. for example username starting from test001 to test100, one by one I do create a all usernames. so this problem I want to create a number of users in a single file( using script) or any of commands kindly guide me! not only creating as well as grant also?

Answer (score 4):

You could try writing SQL-generating SQL.

Try something like this SQL script to get you started:

```
spool create_100_users.sql
select 'create user user'||rownum||' identified by user'||rownum||';' from dual connect by level < 101;
spool off
@create_100_users
```

You can do similar SQL to generate grants, etc.  Just modify the text in the select statement.